# how to alter args of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a plugin that creates a custom post type.  However it doesn't create an archive or make the single posts visible and I would like to change that.

This is the code to register the post type:

```
private static function init_taxonomy() {

    $show_in_menu = current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ? 'woocommerce' : $show_in_menu = true;

    register_post_type( 'wc_product_retailer',
        array(
            'labels'                  => array(
                'name'                => __( 'Retailers', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'singular_name'       => __( 'Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'menu_name'           => _x( 'Retailers', 'Admin menu name', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'add_new'             => __( 'Add Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'edit'                => __( 'Edit', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'new_item'            => __( 'New Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'view'                => __( 'View Retailers', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'view_item'           => __( 'View Retailer', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Search Retailers', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'not_found'           => __( 'No Retailers found', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Retailers found in trash', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
            ),
            'description'             => __( 'This is where you can add new product retailers that you can add to products.', 'woocommerce-product-retailers' ),
            'public'                  => true,
            'show_ui'                 => true,
            'capability_type'         => 'post',
            'capabilities'            => array(
                'publish_posts'       => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'edit_posts'          => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'edit_others_posts'   => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'delete_posts'        => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'delete_others_posts' => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'read_private_posts'  => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'edit_post'           => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'delete_post'         => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
                'read_post'           => 'manage_woocommerce_product_retailers',
            ),
            'publicly_queryable'      => true,
            'exclude_from_search'     => true,
            'show_in_menu'            => $show_in_menu,
            'hierarchical'            => false,
            'rewrite'                 => false,
            'query_var'               => false,
            'supports'                => array( 'title' ),
            'show_in_nav_menus'       => false,
        )
    );
}
```

This is the code I'm using in my functions.php of my child theme.

```
function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

   /*item post type slug*/   
   if ( 'wc_product_retailer' === $post_type ) {
      $args['has_archive'] = true;
   }

   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );
```

It doesn't change anything.

Additionally I've tried directly changing the plugin file by adding

```
'has_archive'  => true,
```

below

```
'show_in_nav_menus'       => false,
```

and then even changing

`show_in_nav_menus` and `query_vars` to true.

Setting `rewrite` to 'my-cool-retailer'.

Each of these changes i've gone to peramlinks settings and hit save.  I've even disabled the plugin and re-enabled it.

Also, on the post edit screen it continues to not show the post slug under the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `query_var` must be `true` or a string if you want any sort of front end display to work, whether or not you use pretty permalinks.

The second part is `rewrite` has to at least be `true`. Note that valid values for `rewrite` are either boolean true/false, or an array. This:

```
$args['rewrite'] = 'my-cool-retailer';
```

... will enable rewrites, but it won't set the slug to `my-cool-retailer`, because a string is not a valid value here, it just gets interpreted as `true`, and your slug will be `wc_product_retailer`.

If you want to set a different slug, you need to make `rewrite` an array with key `slug`:

```
$args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'my-cool-retailer';
```

As for `has_archive`, that's `true` by default, so that works without changing anything but `query_var`. You can also pass a string if you want something other than `wc_product_retailer` to be the archive slug.

So, using your first code block and then setting those two values in the filter works for me when I test on a default install:

```
function change_post_types_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'wc_product_retailer' === $post_type ) {
        $args['query_var'] = true;
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'my-cool-retailer';
   }
   return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_post_types_slug', 10, 2 );
```

One other thing you may want to add is `with_front`, which is `true` by default. This will add any static prefix from your `post` permalink to your CPT, which is usually not desirable.

```
$args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This seemed to work.  I added `has_archive`  and made it true as well, but it doesn't make the permalink show up on the post-edit page.  Is there a way i can get that back too?

Comment: What version are you using? Are you using the new or classic editor?

Comment: wp 5  classic on the custom post

Comment: I think it may be something with the way the plugin is being coded.  When I put the code in by myself it works fine.  With this plugin permalinks don't show on the edit screen and when I use `the_permalink()` in my function doesn't show the postype in the url.  it is `/the-actual-post` instead of `/my-cool-retailer/the-actual-post`